# TypeError when returning data from Flask

Tags: python, flask

I created a Flask server and am exposing a couple endpoints to return some data but I am getting the following error when returning from the method

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple,
        Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a tuple.
```

It's difficult to debug because it is clearly saying that it's returning the correct type.

My method looks like this:

```
def read_schedule_data():
    '''Reads the data from the json file'''
    try:
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), FILENAME)
        with open(file_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        return data, 200
    except IOError:
        return 404
```

As you can see, it just reads a json file and returns its contents.

I also tried doing this

```
def read_schedule_data():
    '''Reads the data from the json file'''
    try:
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), FILENAME)
        with open(file_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        return make_response(data, 200)
    except IOError:
        return make_response('', 404)
```

But that does not work either

Putting breakpoints, it does hit the `return data, 200` line but Flask returns the error above

Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I needed to return as

```
return make_response(jsonify(data), 200)
```

By adding the `jsonify` from Flask, it actually returns the correct data and doesn't fail anymore